If $y_n>0$, $\lim (y_1+\cdots + y_n)=\infty$ and $\lim \frac{x_n}{y_n}=a$, then $\lim \frac{x_1+\cdots+x_n}{y_1+\cdots+y_n}=a$
Problem. Let $y_n>0$ for all $n\in \mathbb{N}$, with $\lim (y_1+\cdots + y_n)=\infty$. Prove that if $\lim \frac{x_n}{y_n}=a$ then $\lim \frac{x_1+\cdots+x_n}{y_1+\cdots+y_n}=a$.
My approach. Let $w_n=y_1+\cdots + y_n$. Since $\lim w_n=\infty$ it follows that $\lim \frac{1}{w_n}=0$. Now, we know that $$\lim \frac{x_1+\cdots+x_n}{y_1+\cdots+y_n}=a \Longleftrightarrow \lim \left(\frac{x_1+\cdots+x_n}{y_1+\cdots+y_n}-a\right)=0$$ and $$\lim \left(\frac{x_1+\cdots+x_n}{y_1+\cdots+y_n}-a\right) = \lim \left[\frac{x_1+\cdots+x_n-a(y_1+\cdots+y_n)}{y_1+\cdots+y_n}\right]=\lim z_n\cdot \frac{1}{w_n},$$ where $z_n=x_1+\cdots+x_n-a(y_1+\cdots+y_n)=(x_1-ay_1)+\cdots +(x_n-ay_n)$. We claim that the sequence $(z_n)$ is bounded. Therefore, $$\lim z_n\cdot \frac{1}{w_n}=0.$$
For this purpose, note that there exists $M>0$ such that $\left|\frac{x_n}{y_n}-a\right|\leq M$ for all $n\in \mathbb{N}$, i.e, $|x_n-ay_n|\leq y_nM$. Thus, $$|x_1-ay_1|+\cdots +|x_n-ay_n|\leq (y_1+\cdots +y_n)M.$$ By the triangular inequality, it follows that $$|z_n|=|(x_1-ay_1)+\cdots +(x_n-ay_n)|\leq (y_1+\cdots +y_n)M.$$ But $(y_1+\cdots +y_n)M$ cannot be considered as a bound of $(z_n)$, since it is not a fixed number (it depends on $n$ itself).
I would be very grateful for a hint to continue.

I think this problem is easily resolved by the Stolz-Cesàro theorem.

This question is a megaduplicate. See for instance Division of two series, and this list.

@AnneBauval Thanks! I will check it out.

$(z_n)$ may be unbounded. Example $x_n=1,y_n=n,a=0,z_n=n$.

@AnneBauval You're right.
